# if i use objects of a class inside another class, can i use a pointer to object of 1st class to point to it's members?

Tags: c++, class, pointers

Here is the code that I have used:
gdb shows a segmentation fault as soon as it starts the constructor. What might I be doing wrong?

```
class Employee
{
public:
    string name;
    int height;
    int level;
    Employee* iboss;
    Employee* parent;
    Employee* left_child;
    Employee* right_child;
    vector<Employee*> junior;
};

class Company
{
private:
    Employee* root;
    Employee* rootAVL;

public:
    Company(void)
    {
        root->junior[0]=NULL;
        root->level=0;
        root->iboss=NULL;
        root->height=0;
        root->left_child=NULL;
        root->right_child=NULL;
        root->parent=NULL;
        rootAVL=root;
    }

    Employee* search(string A, Employee* guy,int c);
    void AddEmployee(string A,string B);
    void DeleteEmployee(string A,string B);
    void LowestCommonBoss(string A,string B);
    void PrintEmployees();
    void insertAVL(Employee* compare,Employee* guy,int c);
    void deleteAVL(Employee* guy);

    void GetName(string A)
    {
        root->name=A;
        cout<<A;
    }       
};

int main()
{
    cout<<"hello world";
    Company C;
    //so the problem seems to be that there's a segmentation fault every time i try to access        root or try to point to it's methods.
    cout<<"hello world";
    string f;
    cin>>f;
    C.GetName(f);
    C.PrintEmployees();
}
```

Here it gives me a segmentation error whenever I try to use `root->junior[0]=NULL` or anything of the sort.

what could be the problem?

Comment: Hint: where does the `root` pointer point to when the `Company()` constructor starts executing?

Comment: root points no where in particular, so what happens when you derefenece it with ->

Comment: i would recommend reading up on pointers a bit more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In class `Compnay` you have:

> ```
> Employee* root;
> ```

and in `Company` constructor you do:

> ```
> root->junior[0]=NULL;
> ```

But you did not construct any instance of `Employee`, so the `root` pointer is *invalid*. So you are just trying to access invalid memory with the aforementioned `root->junior...` line.

Consider creating an `Employee` first.

Note also that if you do `root->junior[0]=...`, then also the `Employee`'s `std::vector junior` data member should be created as a vector containing at least one item (the one with index 0, you are trying to access).

Finally, consider the use of `nullptr` insteaad of `NULL` in C++11/14 code.